# How to display hidden table rows with radio buttons using JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle, hidden

I have multiple table rows that has a set of radio buttons on each row (Approve & Reject). When I select Reject I want to display a hidden tr underneath it and I'm using jquery to insert HTML into the tr. When I select Approve the tr should be hidden once again.

I can't get it to work exactly how I explained it, when I toggle between the Approve & Reject radio buttons the hidden tr gets displayed on all the rows. I want it to only show underneath the radio button I clicked on.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4A7TD/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
        <input type="radio" name="approval1" value="approve" /> APP &nbsp; 
        <input type="radio" name="approval1" value="reject" /> REJ
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hiddenColumn">

 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="left">
        <input type="radio" name="approval2" value="approve" /> APP &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="approval2" value="reject" /> REJ
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hiddenColumn">

 </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
    $('.hiddenColumn').hide();

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'reject') {
       $('.hiddenColumn').show();
       var showColumn = ($(this).closest('tr').next('tr'));
       showColumn.html('<td class="left">*Reason for Rejection<br /><textarea class="width350" name="reasonForRejection"></textarea></td>');
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'approve') {
            ($(this).closest('tr').next('tr')).hide();
       };
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `change` use `click` event and remove this line `$('.hiddenColumn').show()` which is the culprit. Just show the next row by calling show method only on that row which you have already found. Also instead of using `$(this).val()` to get the value, you can just use `this.value` inside the handler.

```
   $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
     var $nextTR = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
     if (this.value == 'reject') {
       $nextTR
       .html('<td class="left">*Reason for Rejection<br /><textarea class="width350" name="reasonForRejection"></textarea></td>')
       .show();
     } 
     else if (this.value == 'approve') {
        $nextTR.hide();
     };
   });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4A7TD/1/)**