# jQuery: Hide or show table row based on radio button checked

Tags: jquery

Couldn't adopt any examples found here, so I'll post this as new question.

I've few table rows, one with radio button:

```
<tr id="catering-types">
    <td colspan="2">Catering Option</td>
    <td>
        <div class="catering-radio-option">
        <label><input type="radio" name="catering_type" id="pickup-only" value="pickup-only" checked="checked">
        Pickup Only</label>
        </div>
        <div class="catering-radio-option">
        <label><input type="radio" name="catering_type" id="delivered" value="delivered">Delivered</label>
        </div>
        <div class="catering-radio-option">
        <label><input type="radio" name="catering_type" id="fully-serviced" value="fully-serviced">Fully Serviced</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and row below that should be hidden or shown, based on what user checked in radio buttons. In this example, table row below only should be shown if user selects "Delivered" radio button, otherwise it should be hidden.

Thanks

George

Comment: you can make customization in the following answer

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115364/how-to-display-hidden-table-rows-with-radio-buttons-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115364/how-to-display-hidden-table-rows-with-radio-buttons-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click handler to the radio buttons.
If checked then you could go *$(this).closest('tr').next().hide();*

*Closest* is the magic function you need.  It searches upwards for the correct selector.

Just add onclick="$(this).closest('tr').next().hide();" as an attribute to to the radiobutton.

This would hide the row **after** the catering-types row. The selector in the click handler would of course have to change for the other types.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, can you update it and include radio button click handler part? Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure if inline js would be good idea. Tried this with `.live( 'change' function() {}`, closest tr didn't worked, but targeting tr id and using `hide()` worked. Thanks anyway